# Django DecimalField what is the maximum value of max_digits?

Tags: django, django-models

Hi i'm trying to design my model which contain a field that supposed to store a really big integer number. Why is it big ? because when the front end send the data up to the server, the float number get converted into integer (for example: 2.44444444 will get converted to 244444444).

The database i'm using is MySql

Reading through the Django [model fields docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#bigintegerfield) i see that bigintegerfield only support up to 9223372036854775807 which is 19 digits(64 bits). I'm afraid that won't be enough so i think i should use DecimalField since it support max_digits like so:

> DecimalField(max_digits=40, decimal_places=0, default=0) #it will act like an integer because decimal_place=0

But i don't know how what the maximum value of `max_digits` since it don't seems to be mentioning about it in the docs and i still can't find any informations about it after googling

If anyone know what the maximum amount `max_digits` in DecimalFields, it would be a great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using MySQL, the maximum number of digits is 65. The number of digits to the right of the decimal point can be up to 30:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html

For PostgreSQL, it is up to 131072 digits before the decimal point and up to 16383 digits after the decimal point:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-numeric.html

SQLite has no real decimal internal type.

Comment: Same amount for mysql 8.0: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html

Answer (score 3):

`max_digits` must be equal, or higher than `decimal_places`.

If you were to have `123456.654321` you'd have to define `max_digits=12, decimal_places=6.`

`max_digits` is INCLUDING `decimal_places`.