# how to convert and save String to float field without rounding it in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a value of the string that is like `30.72044543304425` and am saving it to a `FloatField` as a float.

**example**

```py
my_string = "30.72044543304425"
object = something.objects.get(id=123)
object.myFloatField = float(my_string )
object.save()
```

but the result is

```py
30.7204454330443
```

As you see the number has been rounded ..how to avoid this?

Comment: You can use `DecimalField` or round it on save via `round(float(my_string), 2)`.

Comment: @PatrykSzczepański He does not want it to be rounded

Comment: Ah, sorry - my mistake, I get it. So he should use `DecimalField` as @maciek.glowka mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You might be hitting a maximal possible precision for a float.
You could try to use a DecimalField and manually set the precision to be as high as you need.

I think the limits are pretty high here.

It is DB engine dependent, see here:
[Django DecimalField what is the maximum value of max_digits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59639092/django-decimalfield-what-is-the-maximum-value-of-max-digits)

Comment: this works great, but I had to set decimal_places= 14 .. and sometimes the input has only  13 decimals..which leads to adding a trailing zero .. how to get rid of this?

Comment: Depends how you use the value, but it's probably best to sort this at the latest possible moment - while displaying to the user.

In case of Django templates:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40135464/django-remove-trailing-zeroes-for-a-decimal-in-a-template